# Redirection to form fails with error HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following code I want to use to pass an id to my new form but I'm getting error that resource is not available.

```
    <form action="~/Views/Admin/AdminDemandeurs.cshtml" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnModif" disabled>Modifier</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSupp" disabled>Supprimer</button>
        <input type="text" name="action" id="enregID" />
    </form>
```

I'm using MVC and my view does have an entry in my controller

```
    public ActionResult AdminDemandeurs()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit your form to your action method,not the view.

You may use the  `Url.Action` helper to generate the correct relative path to the action method.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AdminDemandeurs","Admin")" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnModif" disabled>Modifier</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSupp" disabled>Supprimer</button>
        <input type="text" name="action" id="enregID" />
</form>
```